# Are there special rules for using weapons while flying?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, flight

I’m making an Aarakocra fighter and I was curious about how combat works while flying. My character has dual Morningstars and a longbow; I was wondering if both weapons were functional midair. The only things I know is my fly speed and that I can't be wearing heavy armor to use my fly speed.

(I'm not asking about the mechanics of two-handed fighting; I am just curious about flight.)

**Are there any special rules I should be aware of for using weapons while flying?**

Comment: I've edited your question to try to focus on what I think you are asking. Can you confirm this is the question you want answered so that we can reopen it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### There are no special rules for using weapons while flying.

The rules on [movement and position](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MovementandPosition) include a section on [flying movement](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#FlyingMovement):

> Flying creatures enjoy many benefits of mobility, but they must also deal with the danger of falling. If a flying creature is knocked prone, has its speed reduced to 0, or is otherwise deprived of the ability to move, the creature falls, unless it has the ability to hover or it is being held aloft by magic, such as by the *fly* spell.

However, they do not mention weapons, attacks, etc. No other section of this "Combat" chapter mentions how weapons/attacks work while flying, either.

There are no secret rules.

Therefore, there are no special rules for using weapons while flying.